# sed search and replace with spaces

Tags: sed

I am trying to convert the following string

**California_Zephyr_5, on tm** to **California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME**

when I use the following statement this way

```
 # Search and replace
 webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on tm/ON TIME/')
```

I get **California_Zephyr_5, on tm**

If I try it with the individual abbreviations, it seems to work for those:

```
 webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on tm/ON TIME/')
```

results in **California_Zephyr_5, on ON TIME**

```
 webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on tm/ON TIME/')
```

results in **California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME tm**

so I assume the issue is with the space.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it just me or the 3 commands you show are exactly the same? And if they are how could they possibly produce different results?

Comment: Sorry, first time I'm using the stackoverflow form to post. Not sure how that happened.

It should read:

 webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/ tm/on ON TIME/')
results in California_Zephyr_5, on ON TIME

 webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on /ON TIME/')
results in California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME tm

Comment: Please edit your question to fix that. Do not fix it comments, comment are not what SO users search.

Answer (score 1):

There is one non-breaking space after `on` and before `tm`. See with GNU `cat`:

```
echo "$webData" | cat -A
```

Output:

```
California_Zephyr_5, onM-BM- tm$
```

or

```
echo "$webData" | hexdump -C
```

Output:

```
00000000  43 61 6c 69 66 6f 72 6e  69 61 5f 5a 65 70 68 79  |California_Zephy|
00000010  72 5f 35 2c 20 6f 6e c2  a0 74 6d 0a              |r_5, on..tm.|
0000001c
```

I suggest to use:

```
webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on\xc2\xa0tm/ON TIME/')
echo "$webData"
```

Output:

```
California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME
```

Comment: THANK YOU, Cyrus! This has been driving me CRAZY!
It's the only sed statement in my code that was not working.
I also appreciate the cat and hexdump tricks. You can't always get your answers from a book. 
I used: 
webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on\xc2\xa0tm/ON TIME/')

Comment: You are welcome. That would also be possible with `bash`: `webData="${webData/$'\xc2\xa0'/ }"`

Answer (score 0):

BTW you can do this even without `sed`, using just vars:

1.Variable substitution

```
$ webData='California_Zephyr_5, on tm'
$ echo ${webData/on*tm/ON TIME}
California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME
```

2.Using an array

```
$ arr=($webData)
$ echo ${arr[0]} ON TIME
California_Zephyr_5, ON TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one non-breaking space after on and before tm as suggested above.

**echo "$webData" | cat -A** and **echo "$webData" | hexdump -C** demonstrated that.

I used:

webData=$(echo "$webData" | sed 's/on\xc2\xa0tm/ON TIME/')

Thanks for everyone's help.